# Insert multiple photos into a Tumblr post and turn it into an image slideshow

Tags: tumblr

I'm trying to have it so I can add x amount of photos to a Tumblr post and then turn it into a custom image slideshow using jQuery cycle. Is there any way to add x amount of photos to a post and have it spit the images out in a consistent manner? I added 6 and eventually it just points to an iframe that loads their custom slideshow. I don't want to resort to having to edit custom HTML in a post though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photosets give you Photo blocks that you can treat like regular Photo blocks. Just had to add those blocks and have it display in an unordered lists.

[Docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photoset-posts)

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on that answer... Once you have the photo sets being treated as a list of photos, it would be easy to hookup a jQuery plugin to turn them into a slideshow (try nivo or flex slider)